# Capybara+phantomjs = Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm trying to test a creation of PageVote. It works just fine: user clicks on an image, PageVote gets created

But testing it with capybara and phantomjs doesnt work =(

here is the test:

```
it "should change the PageVote after clicking on a vote link", js: true do
   visit page_path( @page, locale: :ru )
   expect( PageVote.count ).to eq(0)
   find("#vote-5").click
   expect( PageVote.count ).to eq(1)
end
```

the controller

```
def create
    Rails.logger.debug "Count before: " + PageVote.count.to_s
    @page = Page.find( params[ :page ] )
    @vote = PageVote.new( ip_address: request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'], vote: params[ :vote ], page: @page )
    @vote.save

    Rails.logger.debug "Count after: " + PageVote.count.to_s

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to page_path( @page ) }
      format.js
    end
end
```

And logs for the test are

```
Started POST "/ru/page_votes?page=1&vote=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-25 22:51:04 +0300
[1m[35m (9.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "page_votes"
Processing by PageVotesController#create as JS
Parameters: {"page"=>"1", "vote"=>"5", "locale"=>"ru"}
```

[1m[36m (2.0ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
    [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "page_votes"
    Count before: 0
    [1m[36mPage Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" INNER JOIN "page_translations" ON      "page_translations"."page_id" = "pages"."id" WHERE "page_translations"."locale" = 'ru' AND "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
    [1m[35mPage::Translation Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "page_translations".* FROM "page_translations"  WHERE "page_translations"."page_id" IN (1)
    [1m[36m (2.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
    [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
    Completed 401 Unauthorized in 38ms

There is no authentication required to make a vote.

Does anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with checking for output, rather than the model count

```
expect(page).to have_content("...")
```

If anyone knows, how to check the count - you're very welcome =)